# Alternate function for xmlSetProp in libxml2

Tags: c, libxml2

I wanted to use xmlSetProp in libxml2 to change a value of a property in a node. But in tree.h and tree.c the function in not enabled. If I try to define

> LIBXML_TREE_ENABLED

It is giving multiple errors. Is there any other function which I can use to change the property or is there any way to solve this and use the xmlSetProp function ?

Please Help. I am using Visual Studio for compiling and the language is C.

Regards,
Vibhu.

Comment: Tree support is an optional feature of the libxml2 set by the `configure` script before it is built. (At least for Unix-like operating systems. I have no idea how the optional features are configured on Windows.) So you either need to find a version of libxml2 built with the required option ([from here](http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/64bit/) for example), or build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott I downloaded the file and replaced the header, I am getting some errors like iconv.h not found.

Comment: I think the libxml headers and libraries have additional dependencies, but they can be downloaded from the same place. However, looking at the [readme.txt](http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/64bit/readme.txt) file in that directory, they are intended for use with a GCC (MinGW) toolchain rather than a Microsoft toolchain (MSVC).